# Sinch and Parse on iOS Compilation Errors using ObjC

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, sinch

I am trying to run an application using the Sinch API and Parse (with the Facebook SDK).

Following the tutorial: 
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/using-sinch-parse-sinch/

I have set "other linker flags" of your target to `-ObjC -Xlinker -lc++` and I have added all of the missing frameworks.

However, I am still seeing the exact same 4 errors listed in this tutorial (image in the top of the page).

My public project repository is here:
https://github.com/rayizam/gc

`Xcode v.6.3`

Comment: The error was  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since you are using social you also need to add the social framweorks,
you might not have to add them all, it depends a little bit on what you use.

```
Accounts.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
Social.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
```

Sorry for the delay

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by removing the Bolts framework and adding the Social Framework (along with the other frameworks listed).